# Is there any method to organize "cycling" (looping) numbers in c++?

Tags: c++

I need to have a cycle of limited number (0 to 3) in an infinite loop. So I use this code:

```
int moveOp = 0;

while (1) {
//some operations with moveOp here
moveOp++;

if(moveOp>3) {
        moveOp = 0;
    }

}
```

But maybe there is a method to have a data type with which increment operator jumps to zero without hand written condition?

Comment: What's wrong with `moveOp = (moveOp + 1) & 3` or `% 4` ?

Comment: In this particular case you can do at each iteration `moveOp &= 3;` instead of the `if` (so you avoid a branch, which is generally nice for performance), but it's not a general method and may not be very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
moveOp = (moveOp + 1) % N;
```

Answer (score 2):

if your NUM is power of 2 you can use the bitfields as well

```
struct {
   unsigned moveOp:2;
}m;

m.moveOp++;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; ; i = (i + 1) % 4) {
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Modulus](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) operator is what you are looking for.
Following is the sample how you can use it:

```
int moveOp = 0;
int Num = 4;

while (1) {
       ++moveOp;
       moveOp = moveOp%Num;
}
```